# Running Gazebo results in Failed request: BadValue

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and ros Indigo. When I try running it, I get the following output:

```
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major optcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor optcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  26
Current serial number in output stream:  27
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Gazebo with no progress. Has anyone encountered something similar to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255747/running-gazebo-results-in-failed-request:-badvalue/) by [hubda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29503/hubda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-28**:
Could you please properly format your questions in the future? Use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it). For console copy-pastes, just select all text and click the button (or use `ctrl+k`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running this in a VM? If yes: 3D accell and VMs are not a good match. If not: do you have proper 3D graphics drivers installed?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hubda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29503/hubda/) on 2017-02-28**:
I'm sorry, I'm new here and didn't think to check for format standards.

In any case, gvdhoorn it's not a VM but I just got a closed-source nvidia driver that supports 3d acceleration and now it works! Thanks!

**Comment by [zishan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32499/zishan/) on 2017-11-04**:
Hi, I am facing the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04.How did u solve this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-05**:\

> How did u solve this?

Apparently @hubda installed the proper NVidia drivers for his platform.